# hide dynamically generated <p> using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm dynamically getting hyperlinks and paragraphs from the database, and I wish to hide/show the paragraphs. How can I use jquery to show/hide only a hidden paragraph of a particular link, instead of showing all the paragraphs?

```
<body>
<a href="#">first link</a>
<p>Show this when I click first link</p>

<a href="#">second link</a>
<p>Show this when I click second link</p>

<script>
$( "p" ).hide();
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "p" ).show();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: For a pure html5 approach (no js or css required), consider trying the  `details` element. Demo of your example here : http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/ULw76/   support of feature:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "p" ).show();
});
```

to:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/C89Pu/)**

Note, you could also toggle between show/hide by using `.toggle()` instead of `.show()` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to give each paragraph a unique id and store that in the link as well. Like this ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nXCby/))

**html**

```
<a href="#" rel="p-1">first link</a>
<p id="p-1">Show this when I click first link</p>

<a href="#" rel="p-2">second link</a>
<p id="p-2">Show this when I click second link</p>
```

**javascript**

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).slideToggle();
});
```

Other options may be, for example, to [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the [first](http://api.jquery.com/first/) [child](http://api.jquery.com/children/) of a certain type (eg a `p`, or a `p` with a [specific class](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)). Whatever way finding the element you want [suits you](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/). What is most appropriate for you mostly depends on how your page is structured.